# Is it possible to move add, delete and list functionality into separate method

Tags: c#, console-application

I am a part-time coder, neither have CS degree and learning on my own. I have written this block of code, my question is, is it possible to move to add, delete or even list functionality into separate method and call them in if statement or main method?

My 2nd question is what does mean by itemAdded == "null"? let's suppose if I added null it says you added nothing?

```
 public void MyMethod()
    {
        var itemList = new List<string>();
        int choices;

        while (true)
        {
            //  Console.Clear();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shopping list:\n1. Add to list\n2. Remove from list\n3. List the items on the shopping list\n4. Exit");
                choices = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                if (choices == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to add in the list?");
                    string itemAdded = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (itemAdded == "null" || itemAdded == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you add nothing!!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        itemList.Add(itemAdded);
                        Console.WriteLine(itemAdded + " is added to the list");
                    }

                }

                else if (choices == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhat would you like to remove from the list?");
                    string itemToRemove = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (itemToRemove == "null" || itemToRemove == "")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you removed nothing");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool isMatch = false;
                        foreach (string item in itemList)
                        {
                            if (item == itemToRemove)
                            {
                                isMatch = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isMatch)//if ismatch is true
                        {
                            itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);
                            Console.WriteLine(itemToRemove + " is successfully removed from your list");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Item is not in the list");
                        }
                    }
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    itemList.Remove(itemToRemove);
                    //    Console.WriteLine(itemToRemove + " is successfully removed from your list");
                    //}
                }

                else if (choices == 3)
                {
                    foreach (string item in itemList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                }

                else if (choices == 4)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("please enter valid choice!!!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You have Entered non-numeric value");
            }
           
        }


    }
```

calling this list into the main method

```
 private static void Main()
    {
        MyClass newClass = new MyClass();

        newClass.MyMethod();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: It's of course possible.  The question is, have you tried?  What happens when you create a method, move your logic to that method, and invoke that method?  If you encounter any errors, have you searched those errors online and attempted to resolve them?  What specifically has you stuck?

Comment: When you loop in a list, you can't remove an item without to raise an error, if you use the foreach loop. I'm not sure but if i remember well, you  don't raise error with a "for" loop, but think to decrease iterator when you remove an item.

Comment: Just create [new methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods). I know you say your a beginner but you should really be reading about programming more if you can't complete this simple task

Answer (score 1):

`itemAdded == "null"` is checking if the user actually typed null. Not if the value is null.

You should really check if a string is null or empty by using the built-in string function

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemAdded))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-5.0

C# is an object-oriented language. This means that how you build an application is built around the idea that each module/class has its own functions. If you were trying to expand this application you could do the following:

1. Build a new class named "ShoppingList" which has several functions. (Add, Remove, Read List).
2. Your main class would read the console input and do what you are currently doing but by communicating with the ShoppingList class
3. Rather than making your shopping list a List object, you should make it a Dictionary. The key would be the item on the list (ex. Milk) and the value would be the quantity (Ex. 2)

An example class layout:

```
public class ShoppingList{
    Dictionary<string, int> _ShoppingList = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public void AddItem(string item){
        if(_ShoppingList.ContainsKey(item)){
           _ShoppingList[item]++;
        }else{
           _ShoppingList.Add(item, 1);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(string item){
        if(_ShoppingList.ContainsKey(item)){
          _ShoppingList[item]--;
          if(_ShoppingList[item] == 0) _ShoppingList.Remove(item);
        }else{
          //nothing to remove
        }
    }
}
```